# Cloning a 500GB disk using Ubuntu Live CD taking more than 10 hrs?

Tags: hard-drive

I am cloning my laptop's 2.5inch 500GB SATA HDD disk to a 2.5 inch Seagate 1000GB (1TB) SSHD disk using an external USB3 SATA Adapter attached to the laptop.

I booted with Ubuntu 14.04 Live CD and I opened a command prompt in the Ubuntu using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and confirmed my both disks are recognized as `dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` using `fdisk` command.

Also the `fdisk` command confirmed that `/dev/sbd` doesn't contain a valid partition table. Then I issued the command `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb` to clone my `/dev/sda` to `dev/sdb`.

It's now more than 10 hours and it still going on, but there is no progress indicator or anything, except the laptop HDD lights are blinking on and off as well the external adapters HDD light blinking on and off.

I estimated this to be over in 4 hrs now its 10 hrs. My laptop is Windows7 and the hdd is encrypted. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Run `sudo pkill -USR1 dd` in another terminal. `dd` will then report statistics.

Comment: @muru Thank you so much, I used your command and I see dd  has copied 209 GB. How can I make it faster? looks like the transfer rate is 5MB/s. Is this normal speed for a Win7 laptop and USB3 adapter?

Comment: @Sansun no, I'd expect it to be at least 6 times as fast. Maybe you could have got better speeds with a different block size. Or maybe one of your disks is falling.

Comment: @kos I have 4 USB2 ports only. Thought the external adapter Kingwin True Dock USB3.0, its cable look to me a regular USB2 cable, not sure there any visible difference to USB2 vs USB3 port or cables.

Comment: Can I terminate this at this time to start all over at the weekend? Will the new drive still will be good after I abort this copying? Tks.

Comment: If you only have USB2 ports, the rest of the setup being USB 3 is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: Didn't see your comment because I deleted mine before you replied; anyway USB 2.0 should cap at 60MB/s, it doesn't explain that speed. Something else is bottlenecking it (not the cable, USB cables are all the same). Unless you're stuffing your USB bus with something else (Wi-Fi dongle, etc) I suspect the adapter being of bad quality

Comment: However yes, the process is safe to be dropped. And thinking about it again probably muru is right: the default `dd` block size (512B) is *very* small. Try with a block size of 1M: `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=1M && sync`. If you want a nice progress bar to check the progress, install `pv` (`sudo apt-get install pv`) and run this command: `sudo pv /dev/sda | sudo dd of=/dev/sdb && sync`